# Why and how did the Community user lock this post?

Tags: discussion, locked-question, community

[This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/295169/can-an-abstract-class-be-instantiated) ([revisions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/295169/revisions)) question was put on hold by users, and then locked by the Community user. I agree that its not a on-topic for this site but

1. Why was it locked? I think putting it on hold is plenty.
2. How did the Community user lock it? I thought only human mods can lock posts.

Comment: Community user is a super-mod bot that will come in and assist normal users with actions that they normally can't do

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yes, but I've never seen community actually lock a post - and this post really has no reason to be locked.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg when posts are migrated away, they are locked to prevent comments and voting on them. The post is eventually deleted if the migration isn't rejected within 30 days.

Comment: @MichaelT Ah, didnt notice the migration. If you make that an answer Ill accept.

Comment: Community user does all sorts of weird things...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a post is migrated to another site, the Community user locks the post to prevent attempts at reopening, votes, and comments (and really, the only way to get to the post is to [?noredirect=1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/295169/can-an-abstract-class-be-instantiated?noredirect=1) in the url).

Eventually (30 days), the post will be deleted if the migration isn't rejected on the other site.

The goal of the combination of the lock and the migration is to direct all future activity on the post on to the other site rather than having it fracture between two different sites.